# How to use re-builder with rx special forms?

Tags: rx

I opened re-builder and changed its syntax to "rx". My target buffer has plenty of digits and (rx (and "4")) highlights a lot of 4s, however, (rx (and digit)) is apparently valid but matches nothing on the same target buffer! So far I only got string literals to match.

Comment: You're certain you're putting `'(and digit)` in the RE-Builder?  I just tested it and it worked fine here. `Emacs 24.4.50.1`

Answer (score 1):

Apparently '(and digit) works. '() is what shows up if one loads re-builder with the syntax already set to "rx". There are some comments in the re-builder.el.gz.